# How to Add Connection for Sql Compact located in App_Data?

Tags: model-view-controller, sql-server-ce

I already have made a Sql Server Compact Database (named testDb.sdf) for my project in MVC. 
I have created the file in App_Data folder, so the address location would be independent from my PC.
The problem is while creating the Connection from the wizard. 
I have already used this address for my Data Source:

```
|DataDirectory|\testDb.sdf
```

I receive this Error after I press Test Connection:

> The database file cannot be found, Check the path to the database. [Data Scource = C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE\testDb.sdf]

[You can see the error in this picture better.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8kggJ.png)

What shall I put in the Data Source address bar?